# show yearly price in InApp Purchase swift ios

Tags: ios, swift3, in-app-purchase

Currently i am working on a iOS App using Swift. I am enabled InApp Purchased. Payment is doing perfectly but when i am showing data from iTunes Connect, the monthly subscription data showing perfectly but i want show price on yearly tab in monthly format with some discount and when user tap on card, it should be show yearly price. I am unable to do this. Description shown in image. Thanks in Advance.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcgD8.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYxy9.png)

[I want show price like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8jva.png)

```
// Currently i am getting product info with this method

  // MARK: - REQUEST IAP PRODUCTS
func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
    if (response.products.count > 0) {
        iapProducts = response.products
       // showHUD("Loading...")

        let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else { return }

       let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

        let firstProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct

        print("localizedDescription", firstProduct.localizedDescription)
         print("localizedTitle", firstProduct.localizedTitle)


        // Get its price from iTunes Connect

        numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.locale = firstProduct.priceLocale
        let price1Str = numberFormatter.string(from: firstProduct.price)

        // Show its description
        cell.monthlyLabel.text = "\(firstProduct.localizedTitle)"
        cell.rupeesLabel.text = "\(price1Str!)"
         cell.perMonthLabel.text = "\(firstProduct.localizedDescription)"

        let indexPath1 = IndexPath.init(row: 1, section: 0)
        guard let cell2 = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath1) as? CollectionViewCell else { return }

        let secondProd = response.products[1] as SKProduct

        // Get its price from iTunes Connect
        numberFormatter.locale = secondProd.priceLocale
        let price2Str = numberFormatter.string(from: secondProd.price)

        // Show its description
        cell2.monthlyLabel.text = "\(secondProd.localizedTitle)"
        cell2.rupeesLabel.text = "\(price2Str!)"
        cell2.perMonthLabel.text = "\(secondProd.localizedDescription)"
        // ------------------------------------

        }
      }
```

Comment: It isn’t clear what you are asking. You should simply show the price that is configured in iTunesConnect, which is what you seem to be doing. It is misleading to show a monthly price for an annual purchase

Comment: Thanks for reply Paulw115. Please see my edited que.

Comment: So write the code that shows that. You will need to divide the price of the annual product by 12. Be careful of rounding since $4.99 * 12 is actually $59.88, which is why I said it is a little misleading.

Comment: Ya but i am unable to find the exact code for this.

Comment: It is basically `secondProd.price / 12`.

Comment: This is not working for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Showing an annual subscription in terms of months is a little more complicated than just dividing by twelve. `SKProduct.price` is an `NSDecimalNumber` class, not a regular float, so standard divide operator doesn't work.

You need to do something like this

```
product.price.dividing(by: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: Decimal(12.0)))
```

This will give you the divided `NSDecimalNumber` which you can pass to the formatter. One problem is that the divided value might round to an incorrect value. The trick is to create a custom `NSDecimalNumberHandler` that rounds as you want.

```
let behavior = NSDecimalNumberHandlerroundingMode: .down, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)
product.price.dividing(by: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: Decimal(12.0)), withBehavior: behavior)
```

That should give you all the control you need to display the annual price at the monthly rate. I would also suggest that you display the total price nearby to not mislead the user too much. There is a fine line between optimizing your purchase flow and trying to scam people.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob Eiting for giving me valuable suggestion. It worked for me after li'll changes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Jacob Eiting. This is worked for me in Swift3.

```
let behavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .down, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)

         let price2Str = numberFormatter.string(from: (secondProd.price.dividing(by: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: Decimal(12.0)), withBehavior: behavior)))

        cell2.rupeesLabel.text = "\(price2Str!)"
```